# How is Sidekiq able to use object from Rails' process space?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multiprocessing, sidekiq

I am trying to wrap my head around background process execution in a Rails app. I have a model with a method that I want to run in the background upon request:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def perform
    perform { MyModel.find(params[:id])&.my_method }
  end
end
```

Rails' numerous queue adapters allow me to do that. I have chosen Sidekiq. Here is my job class:

```rb
class MyMethodJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(id)
    MyModel.find(params[:id])&.my_method
  end
end
```

and back in controller I have

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def perform
    MyMethodJob.perform_later params[:id]
  end
end
```

My understanding is that `MyModel.find(params[:id])&.my_method` is actually performed by one of Sidekiq's worker threads in a different process. In my mind, that means that Sidekiq's process has to be aware of `MyModel` class and its instance methods. I do not understand how a different process is able to successfully manipulate a Ruby object from my Rails app. Does Sidekiq also load all classes from my Rails app into its ObjectSpace? 
At the end of the day, I would like to be able to do something similar to what Sidekiq does - perform a job in a separate process while being able to use code from my Rails app, and access database through Active Record.
I feel like I have a conceptual misunderstanding of how this really works and would really like to figure it out with your help.

Comment: You start Rails with `rails s`. You start Sidekiq with `sidekiq`. Both load the complete application and have access to all its modules and classes and methods. Don't think of it as loading something from your "Rails app." They are separate apps using a shared codebase and connecting to the same database. You can queue jobs from the Rails app; these are pushed to Redis where they are picked up and run by the Sidekiq app.

Comment: Thanks, @anothermh, that makes sense.

Comment: @anothermh where can i get more indepth information like you just explained on sidekiq?

Comment: @MrAfrica https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki